# Getting the unsaved dot on a Swing Mac OSX app with quaqua LAF

Tags: java, macos, swing, quaqua

I am trying to make it so my app shows the unsaved dot in my swing windows when running on Mac  with quaqua LAF.  When I say unsaved dot, I mean in mac apps when you modify something, the red dot in the upper left changes from an empty red circle, to a circle that is mostly filled in with a darker red.  Is there some flag I can set to make this dot show up or disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://nadeausoftware.com/node/90#Settingthetitlebarmodifiedmark) (or the [official Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/technotes/tn2007/tn2196.html#WINDOW_DOCUMENTMODIFIED)).  It's not a feature of Quaqua specifically.